# разница RequestMethod.GET RequestMethod.POST

Tags: spring, http

Не могу найти информация в интернете вообще. Допустим, у меня есть функция

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/whoami", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(@RequestParam String name) {
        return "You are " + name;
    }
```

Задача сделать RequestMethod.POST.
в чем будет разница? Как я понял GET сравнивает адрес и если находит /whoami, то выполняет эту функцию.

Но судя по примеру ниже мое понимание не верно
Нашел в интернете код

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFoosBySimplePath() {
    return "Get some Foos";
}
Чтобы проверить это сопоставление с помощью простой команды curl , запустите:

curl -i http://localhost:8080/ex/foos

Вот простой пример, похожий на предыдущий, но на этот раз сопоставленный с запросом HTTP POST:

@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/hi", method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public String postFoos() {
    return "Post some hi";
}
Чтобы проверить POST с помощью команды curl :

curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8080/ex/hi
```

Я запускаю сервер- пишу в терминале  gradlew bootRun.  и просто перехожу по ссылкам, указанным выше. И GET открывает нормально, а POST нет.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Comment: //ex/hi вы должны отправить POST запрос чтобы получить ответ, переход по ссылкам не получится, ответ не получите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как я понял GET сравнивает адрес и если находит /whoami, то выполняет эту функцию

Немного не так. http клиент (это может быть браузер, или утилита командной строки `curl` или написанная вами программа) когда посылает http запрос всегда указывает http метод и путь. Метод (впрочем как и путь) - это обязательный параметр. `GET` и `POST` - это примеры методов, если и [другие](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Когда сервер получает запрос он его обрабатывает, т.е. генерирует ответ по входным параметрам. В спринге для разных http методов можно задать разные обработчики. Параметр `method` в аннотации `@RequestMapping` и задает http метод. Т.е. спринг будет искать метод контоллера в котором путь, заданный параметром `value` и http метод, заданный параметром `method` совпадают. И вызовет его передав ему входные параметры из запроса (если они есть).

У вас не работает, скорее всего, потому что простой переход по ссылке, или когда вы просто вводите адрес в строку браузера, то выполняется зарос GET. Чтобы выполнить POST нужно либо использовать curl, как у нас написано в вопросе, либо воспользоваться плагином браузера типа [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

Сам код рабочий:

[image: post используя curl]